# Does Isolation Level Serializable avoid All concurrency problems?

Tags: oracle, transactions, isolation-level

In Oracle I ran a query in PL/SQL Developer like this :

```
declare a number;
  begin 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL= SERIALIZABLE';
    select count(*) into a  from item w where w.Item_num='MOH601' ; 
    dbms_output.put_line(a);
  end ;
```

I don't commit or rollback this session , in another session I ran this :

```
begin
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET ISOLATION_LEVEL =SERIALIZABLE';
  insert into item w
    (id, item_num, )
  values
    (200, 'MOH601');
end;
```

As I known serializable doesn't let phantom read , but I can commit this .

Comment: I asked [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567266/phantom-read-anomaly-in-oracle-and-postgresql-does-not-rollback-transaction) because i managed to see an inconsistency in Oracle and PostgreSQL.